Can both $2^x$ and $3^x$ be natural numbers when $x$ is irrational?
By setting $x=\frac {\ln(5)} {\ln(2)}$ the $2^x$ becomes $5$, a natural number. And similarly $3^x$ alone can be a natural number. But is it possible to have both $2^x$ and $3^x$ natural number at the same time with an irrational $x$?

Then $(2/3)^x$ would be rational

@lhf ... $(2/3)^x$ rational, by itself, is possible.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

So our alleged $x$ cannot be algebraic, by Gelfond-Schneider.

According to wikipedia, this is an open number theory problem, and the Four exponentials conjecture implies it.

So you bluffed with an open problem? I am no longer following this question.

I was a victim, I wasn't aware that the problem is open when posting the question.
